# Slow computation using Dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit
import secrets
import string
import pyarrow as pa
from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming
from distributed import Client
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from dask.diagnostics import Profiler, ResourceProfiler, CacheProfiler


def calculate_hash_chunk(chunk, modalities):
    num_modalities = len(modalities)
    def _calculate_hash(chunk):
        if num_modalities == 1:
            return chunk[modalities[0]]
        if num_modalities == 2:
            hash_0 = chunk[modalities[0]]
            hash_1 = chunk[modalities[1]]
            return np.bitwise_xor(hash_0, hash_1)
        if num_modalities == 3:
            hash_0 = chunk[modalities[0]]
            hash_1 = chunk[modalities[1]]
            hash_2 = chunk[modalities[2]]
            return np.bitwise_and(
                        np.bitwise_xor(hash_0, hash_1),
                        np.bitwise_xor(hash_0, hash_2),
                        np.bitwise_xor(hash_1, hash_2))
    return chunk.assign(hash_result=chunk.apply(_calculate_hash, axis=1))


def calculate_hash_df(df, modalities, meta):
    hash_result = {"hash_result": object}
    meta.update(hash_result)
    return df.map_partitions(lambda partition: calculate_hash_chunk(partition, modalities), meta=meta)


def find_closest_points(df, input_list, n):
    # Compute Hamming distance between input list and each row of hash_result column
    distances = dd.from_array(np.array([hamming(input_list, row) for row in df['hash_result']]))
    distances = distances.repartition(npartitions=df.npartitions)
    distances = distances.reset_index(drop=True)
    # Concatenate shot_name and distances columns into a new dataframe
    df = df.assign(distances=distances)
    # Sort by distance and return top n rows
    closest_points = df.compute()
    return closest_points.sort_values(by='distances').head(n)


client = Client(n_workers = 10, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit='5GB')
filename = "AU_AIR_SYNTHETIC_DASK_BIG"
modalities = ["visual", "spatial"]
modalities_long = ["metadata." + x + "_bin_vec" for x in modalities]
all_modalities = ["visual", "spatial", "temporal"]
all_modalities_long = ["metadata." + x + "_bin_vec" for x in all_modalities]

read_ddf = dd.read_parquet(filename, engine='pyarrow', blocksize="256MB", columns =  ["shot_name"] + modalities_long)
ddf = read_ddf

meta_end = {
    (modality): 'object' for modality in modalities_long}
meta = {"shot_name": str}
meta.update(meta_end)

ddf = calculate_hash_df(ddf, modalities_long, meta = meta)
searching_hash = ddf[ddf["shot_name"] == "frame05.jpg"]["hash_result"].compute().values[0]
find_closest_points(ddf, searching_hash, 10)
```

Here, the data is in parquet format and repartitioned using 20 parts.
When I launch the code to get see why it is so slow, I get the following:

[image]

The yellow parts are getitem and the big blues are assign.
I noticed that the code after reading the files is not being executed in parallel.

I also noticed that here:

```
np.array([hamming(input_list, row) for row in df['hash_result']])
```

I'm performing list comprehension, so it's basically locking the threads. Is there any way to achieve this calculation in a dask manner so it performs in parallel?

Comment: Any chance you can boil all that code down to the bare essentials to show the problem?